# want to customize myfontend url using yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I am developing a yii app and I want to customize my url like the following

```
example.com/site/mypages/page1 ==> example.com/page1
```

My file structure is like,

```
protected -> views -> site -> mypages -> pages
```

and I use site controller for my mypages folder also.

How can I produce urls in the above format?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this rule in your url-manager:

```
 'urlManager' => array(
         ...
        'rules' => array(
            "page1"=> "site/mypages/page1"
             ...
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: hi hamed, it returns the following error - Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "Radio".

Comment: Hi, what's the "Radio"? Can you post the url that throws 404 error?

Comment: thats my page name (page1)

Comment: its an local site (under developing)

Comment: Ok, can you post the url?

Comment: its in local server only